# How can I prevent my Azure Databricks Cluster's driver from accumulating memory and restarting frequently due to OOM?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, out-of-memory, azure-databricks

Azure Databricks Cluster's Driver Restarts after every nth hour due to *OOM*.

**Context**

1- I'm using Databricks Interactive Clusters due to 5 mint SLA.
2- Around 24 jobs are executing at the same time and executed around 2-3 minutes of the window.

I've attached the picture for the cluster RAM size in which the driver is highlighted where the driver restarts. My question is, why the driver is accumulating the memory and then restarting after, say every nth hour? I'm not using any `collect()`, `display()` or converting Pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe.

There are 4 interactive clusters that are up and running, and all are experiencing a similar issue because all clusters are executing similar jobs/code but with different parameters.

As per my knowledge Driver should Flush out the memory after the completion of the jobs.

What else can I look for to resolve this issue?

**Stderror**

```py
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:719)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.startServerConnection(ClientServerConnection.java:110)
at py4j.JavaServer.createConnection(JavaServer.java:122)
at py4j.GatewayServer.processSocket(GatewayServer.java:680)
at py4j.GatewayServer.run(GatewayServer.java:706)
at py4j.GatewayServer.start(GatewayServer.java:789)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase$Gateway.$anonfun$run$5(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:814)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverLocal$TrapExitInternal$.trapExit(DriverLocal.scala:1267)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase$Gateway.$anonfun$run$3(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:814)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase$Gateway.retry(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:819)
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverLocalBase$Gateway.run(PythonDriverLocalBase.scala:808)
```

Now I'm also seeing below error as well.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:719)
    at zeromq_shaded.zmq.poll.Poller.start(Poller.java:181)
    at zeromq_shaded.zmq.Reaper.start(Reaper.java:58)
    at zeromq_shaded.zmq.Ctx.initSlots(Ctx.java:446)
    at zeromq_shaded.zmq.Ctx.createSocket(Ctx.java:388)
    at zeromq_shaded.org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<init>(ZMQ.java:836)
    at zeromq_shaded.org.zeromq.ZMQ$Socket.<init>(ZMQ.java:822)
    at zeromq_shaded.org.zeromq.ZMQ$Context.socket(ZMQ.java:655)
    at zeromq_shaded.org.zeromq.ZContext.createSocket(ZContext.java:133)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterClient.connect(JupyterClient.scala:252)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterClient.<init>(JupyterClient.scala:258)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.$anonfun$startPython$1(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:698)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.com$databricks$backend$daemon$driver$JupyterDriverLocal$$withRetry(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:663)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.startPython(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:680)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.JupyterDriverLocal.<init>(JupyterDriverLocal.scala:403)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.PythonDriverWrapper.instantiateDriver(DriverWrapper.scala:781)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.setupRepl(DriverWrapper.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DriverWrapper.run(DriverWrapper.scala:246)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Ganglia Memory Graph of the Cluster:

[image: img]

I've tried increasing the driver memory, but there is no improvement though the restart time got delayed.

Comment: Memory doesn't seem to be the issue. Somewhere someone is not cleaning up threads or these threads get blocked on an external call and are unable to finish. Do you have a hunch of what that might be?

Comment: @MennovanLavieren I seriously have no idea, by reading the error that is unable to create native thread, I'm also not able to find anything useful to find the root cause that is why I initiated this question on this platform.

Comment: I understand the stressful situation. Unfortunately I can't give any help. I was hoping that providing some more information might increase the chance that someone could recognize the situation and provide an answer.

Comment: @MennovanLavieren Thanks for your concerns.  I can provide more information if anyone can point me in the direction, what is more required from my side.

Comment: Can you provide what the configuration of your used cluster (RAM), and are you using it somewhere in your code `.toPandas()`? what is the size of your data?

Comment: @Mario 
My Cluster Driver RAM is 64 GB. Previously it was 56GB, then I increased it to 64 but problem of driver restarting persists.
 I'm not using .toPandas() function in my code and my data size would be Around 45K rows per 5 minutes across all 24 jobs.

Answer (score 0):

My Understanding is that resolving the Azure Databricks cluster's driver restarting due to out-of-memory (OOM) is You can use *the Memory Usage Analysis method*, for example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MemoryUsageAnalysis").getOrCreate()

# Generate sample data
data = spark.range(1000000).selectExpr("rand() as value")

# Perform memory-intensive operations
result = data.select(sum("value")).collect()[0][0]

# Print result
print(result)

# Stop SparkSession
spark.stop()
```

With the help of the above code, you can observe the memory usage.
If the driver runs out of memory and restarts, you can monitor the cluster's logs to determine the cause of the out-of-memory errors.
[image]

Comment: My issue is I'm not getting driver restart when I execute the jobs, jobs are scheduled, and driver is keep accumulating memory instead of releasing the memory and after 8-9 hour driver restarts, as you can see in the Ganglia graph which I uploaded for the reference.  I want to why driver is accumulating the memory, even though 4 worker nodes are available to do the processing.

Comment: I think no of  concurrent jobs running on your cluster is causing excessive memory pressure on the driver node.